# How can I change a .properties file in maven depending on my profile?

Tags: maven-2, properties

How can I change a .properties file in maven depending on my profile?  Depending on whether the application is built to run on a workstation or the datacenter parts of the file my_config.properties change (but not all).

Currently I manually change the .properties file within the .war file after hudson builds each version.

Comment: can you please review, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51186963/value-from-maven-profile-properties-is-not-getting-used-in-properties-file

Answer (score 71, accepted):

As often, there are several ways to implement this kind of things. But most of them are variations around the same features: profiles and **filtering**. I'll show the most simple approach.

First, enable filtering of resources:

```
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
      </resource>
    </resources>
    ...
  </build>
</project>
```

Then, declare a place holder in your `src/main/resources/my_config.properties`, for example:

```
myprop1 = somevalue
myprop2 = ${foo.bar}
```

Finally, declare properties and their values in a profile:

```
<project>
  ...
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>env-dev</id>
      <activation>
        <property>
          <name>env</name>
          <value>dev</value>
        </property>
      </activation>
      <properties>
        <foo.bar>othervalue</foo.bar>
      </properties>
    </profile>
    ...
  </profiles>
</project>
```

And run maven with a given profile:

```
$ mvn process-resources -Denv=dev
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
...
$ cat target/classes/my_config.properties 
myprop1 = somevalue
myprop2 = othervalue
```

As I said, there are variation around this approach (e.g. you can place values to filter in files), but this will get you started.

#### References

- [Introduction to Build Profiles](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html)
- [Maven Resources Filtering](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html)

#### More resources

- [A Maven2 multi-environment filter setup](http://sujitpal.blogspot.com/2006/10/maven2-multi-environment-filter-setup.html)
- [Maven project filtering](http://www.waltercedric.com/java-j2ee-mainmenu-53/361-maven-build-system/1639-maven-project-filtering.html)
- [Using Maven profiles and resource filtering](http://www.manydesigns.com/documentation/tutorials/using-maven-profiles-and-resource-filtering.html)
- [Building For Different Environments with Maven 2](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-building-for-different-environments.html)

Comment: If using `Spring Boot` thins would be slightly different. https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-properties-and-configuration.html

Comment: I couldn't get it working, can you please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51186963/value-from-maven-profile-properties-is-not-getting-used-in-properties-file

Comment: Works perfectly for me! I configured sentry.io with this thanks for that :D