# Where to place properties files when running tests via maven + grizzly + jersey test framework?

Tags: maven, junit, jersey, grizzly

The `my.properties` file from my source (`src/main/resources`) folder keepa getting picked up and used when I try to run my `JerseyTest` ... whereas I would like the properties files in the test folder (`src/test/resources`) to be utilized.

```
ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
try {
    myProperties.load(classLoader.getResourceAsStream("my.properties"));
}
```

How can I configure this in Maven?

I'm using:

1. `maven-compiler-plugin` version `2.1`
2. `jersey-test-framework-grizzly2` version `1.13`

---

UPDATE (Resolved based on accepted answer):

I noticed the text `skip non existing resourceDirectory`:

```
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.4.3:testResources (default-testResources) @ xxx ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (MacRoman actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/src/test/resources
```

Turns out that I had misspelled resources, after fixing it, everything works as outlined in the accepted answer.

While I was wasting my time looking for workarounds, I did find some interesting links for configuring properties files based on profiles:

1. [How can I change a .properties file in maven depending on my profile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3868310/how-can-i-change-a-properties-file-in-maven-depending-on-my-profile)
2. http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-building-for-different-environments.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When running something from the `src/test/java` folder, the *default behavior* is:

- It will pick up the files in `src/main/resources`;
- Except when there is a file with the same name in `src/test/resources`.

So basically it will "overwrite" the content of `src/main/resources` with the content of `src/test/resources`:

- If you got a file in **both folders**, the one in `src/test/resources` will prevail.
- If you got a file only in `src/main/resources`, it will be used.
- If you got a file only in `src/test/resources`, it will be used.

Comment: I understand what you are saying but it picks up the one in `src/main/resources` even when there is a fiel with the same name in `src/test/resources` ... any other suggestions?