# Unable to write into properties file from maven

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, spring-boot-maven-plugin

I have a properties file in resource directory of my project and want to  to write some property values by maven command when project build based on profile. Properties file look like this (application.properties):

```
server.port=${server.port}
report.workspacePath=${reporting.workspacePath}
server.path=/foo/foosame
 server.filePath=/bar/bardir
```

this how my pom file look like:

```
  <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>server</id>
            <properties>
                <server.port>8080</server.port>
                <reporting.workspacePath>/opt/reporting/backend2-instance/reporting</reporting.workspacePath>
            </properties>
        </profile>

<profile>
            <id>staging</id>
            <properties>
                <server.port>8084</server.port>
                <reporting.workspacePath>/opt/reporting/backend1-instance/reporting</reporting.workspacePath>
            </properties>
        </profile>

        </profiles>
     <build>
            <resources>
                <resource>
                    <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                    <!--<excludes>
                        <exclude>*.properties</exclude>
                    </excludes> -->
                    <filtering>true</filtering>
                </resource>
            </resources>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.2</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>copy-resources</id>
                            <phase>compile</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>

       <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/</outputDirectory>
                                <resources>
                                    <resource>

        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                                        <excludes>
                                            <exclude>*.txt</exclude>
                                        </excludes>
                                        <filtering>true</filtering>
                                    </resource>
                                </resources>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
```

But nothing writing into properties file when i run maven command like this:

```
mvn -Pstaging clean package
```

Can someone have clue what i am missing here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I change a .properties file in maven depending on my profile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3868310/how-can-i-change-a-properties-file-in-maven-depending-on-my-profile)

Comment: Perfect. So for springBoot application your properties file should be look like this @server.port@

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-properties-and-configuration.html

Comment: You should use spring boot profiles and not Maven profiles...